# Connect QML with C++ without Singleton

Tags: c++, qt, qml, singleton

In general accessing C++ functions from QML is easy. With `qmlRegisterType` a C++ class can be instantiated and accessed.

But if I do this, this C++ function is not connected with the rest of the C++ project. In my case I use `Singletons` to access specific parts of the project. Is there any other, better, possiblity to connect this C++ backend with the rest of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a C++-side singleton to QML-side as well (note this is C++11):

in your main:

```
MyBackend *myBackend = new MyBackend();
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyBackend>("my.namespace", 1, 0, 
    [=](QQmlEngine*, QJSEngine*) -> QObject*
    {
        eng->setObjectOwnership(myBackend, QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership::CppOwnership);
        return myBackend;
    }
);
```

Note, this is geared towards dependency injection, where you have a single instance in a central place and distribute that to classes that need it, instead of having a static instance somewhere with all the trouble that can cause. You can still rewrite to static instance if you insist.